# Get event in a subscribe function in knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I'm wondering if it is possible to get the `event` parameter in the `subscribe` function of knockout.js.

```
self.selectedOrder.subscribe(function(newValue, action) {
    shouter.notifySubscribers(newValue, "selectedOrder");
});
```

I have a table with rows and I would like to notify other viewmodels when the user clicks over a row to select it.

I need the `event` parameter to get the `$(event.currentTarget)` element and highlight the row by adding a CSS class.

```
$(event.currentTarget).addClasss('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
```

I was thinking about doing it directly with KO, but I didn't find a proper way. It doesn't seem easy...

[This was my try with KO](http://jsfiddle.net/vhwk1gvy/9/). Basically:

```
data-bind="css: {'selected':  $parent.selectedUser().id == id}"
```

Which of course, was throwing errors when `selectedUser` was null.

After reading [this article](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/08/simplifying-and-cleaning-up-views-in.html) about *protecting against null objects*, I just though KO is not as easy as jQuery for this task. So I believe I will go for the traditional jQuery in this case as it is much straight forward.

The problem is, I still need the `event` object.

Comment: Try `css: {'selected':  $parent.selectedUser() && $parent.selectedUser().id == id}`. Also, in `self.editName = function(data, e) {` you have the `event` as the `e` parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which of course, was throwing errors when selectedUser was null.

You could do this very simply with the addition of a function onto your `ViewModel`

```
self.isSelected = function(id){
    return self.selectedUser() && self.selectedUser().id == id;   
}
```

And a simple change to your markup:

```
<tr data-bind="click: $parent.selectRow, attr: {'id': id}, css: {'selected':  $parent.isSelected(id)}, clickBubble: false">
  here -----------------------------------------------------------------------^
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vhwk1gvy/10/